# unable to use two sliders together

Tags: jquery, html, slider

i am using two sliders for my web page but only one can run at a time , i want them to work simultaneously , both  at a time , here are the links for two sliders

1: http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.5/05.html
2:http://www.queness.com/resources/html/slideshow/jquery-slideshow.html

i saw their source codes and applied it on my page but only one can run at a time, they both uses jquery files in a js folder , i,ve included all required files given in the source code but not giving desired results do anybody have any idea about this please share it here Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with *IIFE* syntax like this:

```
(function($){
   $(function(){
      // code for first slider here
   });
})(jQuery);

(function($){
   $(function(){
      // code for second slider here
   });
})(jQuery);
```

or maybe you want to take a look @ [**`jQuery.noConflict()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

---

### Update for your latest comment:

As you are using two jQuery libraries then you should do this -

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $ = jQuery.noConflict(true); // <---important to pass the true boolean
    // here your slider code
</script>

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $ = jQuery.noConflict(true); // <---important to pass the true boolean
    // here your show/hide code
</script>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah that would also be great.

Comment: done, its working thanks @Jai ... thanks for  jQuery.noConflict()...i want to ask one more thing how about adding a simple script """"<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"""" from this site """http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_show_hide"""this would be the third version but i've applied it to show/hide a div and without this i can not use "slow" attribute in show/hide function

Comment: @MunanshuMadaan oops its a late reply but nonetheless you just make sure to do like this: `.hide("slow");`.

Comment: yes i've done this but i need to include this """<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"""which results in previous problem ... 1st slider doesn't work again...then what should i do ???

Comment: Okay and what about other version of jquery, would you tell that version too.

Comment: 1:-<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.5.js"></script>   2:-<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>  ...these are the script i m using for both sliders but when i use this """<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>""" it doesn't work

Comment: no its not working .. it displays it as a text """$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);""" and still gives the same result...... i've tried transition delay, duration properties its working good but i've to include this for all browsers ...thats why i was asking for javascript method